# Mongo: Sum Value in a Field with map/reduce

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a collection that looks like so:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("foo-1"),
    "status" : "good",
    "value" : "100.00"
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("foo-2"),
    "status" : "good",
    "value" : "100.00"
}
```

I'd like to get two things:

- Total "value" of all objects
- Total "value of all objects with particular status

Here are my map/reduce functions:

```
var map = function () {
    emit("total", {sum: this.value )) 
    }

var reduce = function (key, values) {
    var result = {sum:0};
    values.forEach(function (value) {result.sum += value.value;});
    return result;
    }

var t = db.leads.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out : "total"});
db[t.result].find();
```

The output of the above is:

```
PRIMARY> db[t.result].find();
{ "_id" : "total", "value" : { "sum" : NaN } }
```

Why is "sum" coming back NaN?

Answer (score 0):

In your reduce function-

```
{result.sum += value.value;}
```

But you're emitting documents with a "sum" field. Try:

```
{result.sum += value.sum;}
```